# Prev and next button in slick not appearing in slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I am working with the jQuery slick.js slider. It's working well but I have an issue with arrows. I need a simple next and previous button which is not appearing with my below code:

```js
$('.your-class').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    arrow: true,
    prevArrow: "<button type='button' class='slick-prev'>Previous</button>",
    nextArrow: "<button type='button' class='slick-next'>next</button>"
});
```

```css
.your-class {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple slides that require the prev/next buttons to be shown?

Comment: yep not include here.but i have more than 6 and i can swipe both left and right only issue is prev and next button not appearing

Comment: do you have a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/187/)

Comment: David, how is anyone supposed to fixed this without seeing the whole code

Comment: Please make a http://jsfiddle.net/ or at least show us the whole code, otherwise we can't help you.